# iPhone backlight changes it’s brightness

Tags: iphone, display

When reading things on my iPhone, the backlight will get brighter by itself, and I don’t really acknowledge but I guess it dims then gets bright again.

Comment: Yup, they do that. Annoying, isn't it? I've never found a way to prevent it.